# PHP/MYSQL: table was not created in wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

when I run this php file in my wamp server it connects to database, selects database but not create table .
the output is this:

```
connected to database succussfully.
connected to database store_db succussfully.
table users was not created.
```

what is the problem??? 
**php code:**

```
<?php
$sql='CREATE TABLE users
(
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
NAME CHAR(20),
PASSWORD CHAR(15),
)';

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('could not connect to database.');
echo 'connected to database succussfully.<br>';

mysql_select_db('store_db') or die('database store_db not found.');
echo 'connected to database store_db succussfully.<br>';

mysql_query($sql) or die('table users was not created');
echo 'table users was created in database store_db succussfully.<br>';

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql='CREATE TABLE users
(
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
NAME CHAR(20),
PASSWORD CHAR(15),
)';
```

remove the comma after `PASSWORD CHAR(15),`

in the event of an error, you can always retrieve errors using `mysql_error()`.

however. you should not be using the old mysql functions. much better and more secure options exist in the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Your $sql:

```
$sql='CREATE TABLE users
(
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
NAME CHAR(20),
PASSWORD CHAR(15),
)';
```

should be:

```
$sql='CREATE TABLE users
(
PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(PID),
NAME CHAR(20),
PASSWORD CHAR(15)
)';
```

You should remove comma right after PASSWORD CHAR(15)

Answer (score 0):

To get the proper error message always use below code so that you can figure out exact error in future.

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Instead of guessing just use code similar to above  ,so that you may figure out exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the MySQL user you are attempting to create the table with has permissions to do so. (e.g. the user has been granted the 'CREATE' privileges for that database.)